# laravel 8 form submission, how to access values of dropdown select

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

I am updating a record in laravel, and upon submission of my form, the $request data returns as:

```
{
  "_token":"dz0r6l1RFu9pWD4cfFnkcVDNczr6u2DBS5zrR14n",
  "_method":"PUT",
  "\u201cclient_id\u201d":"1",
  "\u201cappt_type_id\u201d":"11",
  "\u201cappt_status_id\u201d":"2",
  "appt_note":"Test note",
  "subjective":"test",
  "assessment":"test update",
  "plan":"test p"
}
```

Everything updates EXCEPT the client_id, appt_type_id, and appt_status_id fields, which are dropdown selects.  The correct (updated) values are in that data, but how do I access it so I can update the record?

Comment: I was able to access the values using the laravel collective's html forms tool, but I'd love to understand what is happening, and how to do this with simple html/php.

Comment: Can you show the function that you use to store the data? The clou should be in there. Maybe add the model you are storing as well. This might be a problem with `$fillable` in the model, if you are using `Model::create()` for instance

Comment: Sure.  It's the exact same code, but once I used Laravel Collective's form elements it updated the fields correctly.
`$appt = Appt::find($id);

        $appt->update($request->all());`

Comment: Does the `Appt` model have `client_id`, `appt_type_id` and  `appt_status_id` in `$fillables`? Because with your current setup it is required.

Comment: Yes.  Basically, I was wondering how to access the data in those fields?  Is there a reason the data looks encrypted for dropdown when using html forms instead of the laravel collective forms?